# Unable to set hostname for use within network

Tags: ubuntu, dhcp, hostname

I am having a lot of trouble setting up a hostname for my home server for use within my home network. My home server is running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and all packages are up to date. Management of this server is done using SSH only, no GUI is present.
I want to use the servers host name mainly for accessing web pages and samba shares from several Windows computers and Android devices.

My homeserver acquires its (static) IP address from a Linksys WRT54GC using DHCP.
Both `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/hostname` have added "homeserver" as a host name.
I did not tamper `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`, because the default settings should work according to Ubuntu sources.

The router is only able to resolve host names for DHCP clients. It does not let me edit the client names like some newer products can.
All host names of my Windows PC are recognized by the router. I am also able to ping those machines using their host names. So everything seems to be all right on my router.

The Linksys WRT54GC is cascaded to an ISP configured DSL modem/router. All internet traffic is routed to the Linksys, as it is placed in the DMZ of the DSL modem/router. The IP address of the DSL modem/router is 192.168.1.1 and the Linksys is 192.168.2.1. The Linksys is configured using a static IP address. The DNS server for the Linksys is configured to 192.168.1.1. All clients linked to the Linksys report having 192.168.**1**.1 as the DNS server.

This issue might have something to do with [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/isc-dhcp/+bug/1006937) bug.
I have installed the `isc-dhcp-client` package from 13.04, but that did not do the trick.
If this bug still exist in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (and 13.04), I would like to know a work around.

#### Edit #1

The OP [posted the contents](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5688298/) of the file: `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`:

```
# Configuration file for /sbin/dhclient, which is included in Debian's
#   dhcp3-client package.
#
# This is a sample configuration file for dhclient. See dhclient.conf's
#   man page for more information about the syntax of this file
#   and a more comprehensive list of the parameters understood by
#   dhclient.
#
# Normally, if the DHCP server provides reasonable information and does
#   not leave anything out (like the domain name, for example), then
#   few changes must be made to this file, if any.
#

option rfc3442-classless-static-routes code 121 = array of unsigned integer 8;

send host-name "<hostname>";
#send dhcp-client-identifier 1:0:a0:24:ab:fb:9c;
#send dhcp-lease-time 3600;
#supersede domain-name "fugue.com home.vix.com";
#prepend domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1;
request subnet-mask, broadcast-address, time-offset, routers,
    domain-name, domain-name-servers, domain-search, host-name,
    netbios-name-servers, netbios-scope, interface-mtu,
    rfc3442-classless-static-routes, ntp-servers,
    dhcp6.domain-search, dhcp6.fqdn,
    dhcp6.name-servers, dhcp6.sntp-servers;
#require subnet-mask, domain-name-servers;
#timeout 60;
#retry 60;
#reboot 10;
#select-timeout 5;
#initial-interval 2;
#script "/etc/dhcp3/dhclient-script";
#media "-link0 -link1 -link2", "link0 link1";
#reject 192.33.137.209;

#alias {
#  interface "eth0";
#  fixed-address 192.5.5.213;
#  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.255;
#}

#lease {
#  interface "eth0";
#  fixed-address 192.33.137.200;
#  medium "link0 link1";
#  option host-name "andare.swiftmedia.com";
#  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
#  option broadcast-address 192.33.137.255;
#  option routers 192.33.137.250;
#  option domain-name-servers 127.0.0.1;
#  renew 2 2000/1/12 00:00:01;
#  rebind 2 2000/1/12 00:00:01;
#  expire 2 2000/1/12 00:00:01;
#}
```

Comment: Alain, it is to me unclear what you try to achieve in the end. Do you want to be able to access something like `http://homeserver/you_pages` from your windows machines and is that not working? In other words, how do you want to use that hostname and which machine/box is not resolving it (and I think that it is not the router not knowing that bothers you).

Comment: I think it would help if you posted the contents of `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`. Also, how are you managing the connection? Are you using a GUI like `NetworkManager` or `wicd` or doing it via `/etc/network/interfaces`?

Comment: @Anthon: I updated my question with the requested information (Please say so if this comment is unnecessary for notifying you of any changes in the question. I am relatively new here.)

Comment: @Joseph R.: I am managing the server using SSH only. I will post you the contents of /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf later.

Comment: @Alain As you probably noticed by now, you get a notification of edits to or comments on your post on the upper left 'stackexchange'. However I only got the notification because you used `@Anthon`. The system has no other way of knowing which comment you answered if there are multiple, so you did the right thing.

Comment: I have a similar setup with 2 machines under 12.04 and several windows clients. I am pretty sure my windows machines find the server using its hostname, because `samba` is running they use NetBIOS name resolution. My Ubuntu workstation needs an entry in `/etc/hosts` for that, without it, it cannot find the server by hostname.
As a stopgap, you might just want to add an entry in `%Systemroot%\System32\Drivers\Etc` on each of the windows machines, especially if the IP of the server is fixed.

Comment: possible dupliate: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/75910/setting-a-network-hostname-doesnt-work/76044#76044

Comment: @Joseph R.: Please find the the contents of `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` on [this](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5688298/) PasteBin.

Comment: @Alain Thanks. Nothing seems untoward there... I think your best bet is to follow the suggestion of slm in the comment he/she made on the answer below. I recently had a similar situation and the problem was that `/etc/resolv.conf` was set to query my router and not my DNS server.

Answer (score 2):

If your DHCP server supports it you might want to try and have your client send the desired hostname that it wants. Add the following to the file `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`:

```
send host-name 'your-hostname-here';
```

If you want to send a fully qualified domain name (fqdn) - myhost.mydomain.com instead of just myhost you need to add these lines too:

```
send fqdn.fqdn "myhost.mydomain.com.";
send fqdn.encoded on;
send fqdn.server-update off;
also request fqdn, dhcp6.fqdn;
```

#### Edit #1

The OP was asked to try the following commands and report back:

```
dig <hostname> @<router ip>
```

The OP reported that this worked so it was determined to try adding the router's IP explicitly to his `dhclient.conf` file.

#### Edit #2

It was suggested to try adding the following to the `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` file:

```
prepend domain-name-servers 192.168.2.1;
```

#### Edit #3

Given you're able to now ping servers using your router's DNS server when you added 192.168.2.1, but not the internet, I would suggest you add some external DNS servers as well using the above prepend option like so:

```
prepend domain-name-servers 192.168.2.1, 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;
```

This will add your router as a DNS resolver along with Google's DNS servers.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. However, the following line already exists in the default `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS: `send host-name "<hostname>";` Where `<hostname>` is substituted by the contents of `/etc/hostname`  To rule things out; I have also explicitly configured the hostname without effect.

Comment: The hostnames of all Windows PC's do show up correctly on the router and can be pinged from each other. Does it make any sense to use the `dig` command from the server to any of the Windows PC's or does it have to be a Linux machine as well?

Comment: I was able to resolve the IP address of a Windows PC using the `dig <hostname> @<router ip>` command as indicated. I also used the command with the hostname of the server. The router actually answered with the correct IP address! I am clueless...

Comment: That's actually good news. So the router's DHCP server is getting the hostname and associating it w/ the IP address it's assigning to it. So the issue might be that the server's /etc/resolv.conf file doesn't include the router's IP address as the first DNS server to query against. Did the `dig` command work on the Linux server too?

Comment: @Alain You may also want to note whether the changes you make to `/etc/resolv.conf` are persistent after reboot because they may be overwritten by `NetworkManager` or similar software unless you define your connection in `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Comment: @slm: The IP address of the Linksys router is `192.168.2.1`. The DNS server according to `/etc/resolv.conf` is `192.168.1.1`, which is the IP address of a DSL modem/router. However, the configuration file is automatically configured from the DHCP server and manual changes are overwritten as indicated by Joseph R. I have updated my question with more information about the network topology. The `dig` command did indeed work on the server.

Comment: @Joseph R. Thanks for you pointing me out. I found out yesterday that the contents of `/etc/resolv.conf` are retrieved from the DHCP server. I have updated my question with more information about the network topology.

Comment: @Alain I posted the same solution before I saw this comment.  I second this suggestion.

Comment: @slm: I have modified `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` as indicated. I am able to ping Windows clients now from the Linux server using hostnames. However I am still unable to access any website, samba share or even ping the server from Windows PC's. Using `nslookup homeserver` on Windows machines result in the correct IP address. (I had to change DNS servers manually to `192.168.2.1`) The homeserver also shows up in Windows Explorer, but is inaccessible. FYI: these problems started when I migrated from a FritzBox 7113 modem/router to my current setup. This device allowed known hostname modification.

Comment: @Alain If your server turned up correctly via `nslookup` and you can see it in `Windows Explorer`, in what way exactly is it "inaccessible"? Why not edit the DHCP server to make your `homeserver` the primary DNS and your ISP modem the secondary one, so that the Windows PCs would automatically know to query your server first?

Comment: Why not change the DHCP server to do that instead of changing all the DHCP clients?

Comment: @JosephR., that's what I would do but the OP doesn't seem to either understand that or there is something wonky with his router that's providing that feature. You'd have to ask him for sure. This question is turning into "too localized" to be of value, so I'm trying to get his particular issue resolved without dragging it out further.

Comment: @slm: I thought I had double checked every relevant configuration file before posting my last comment... The moment I stepped into bed yesterday, it came into my mind that the subnet was changed when I migrated to my current setup. The firewall on `homeserver` is still configured using the old subnet...  Sorry for making this question a mess, I will filter out the essentials when everything is up and running. Thank you for your help and patience!

Comment: @Alain - You might want to post some screenshots of the contents of the setup screens from this router. We're all kind of flying blind and fix the issue on your Linux box when I have a suspicion that the issue is with the router.

Comment: @slm: A screenshot of the `Basic Setup` tab on my router: http://imgur.com/rbd6At3

Comment: @Alain - You need to specify the correct DNS server IP's in that screen. You have 192.168.1.1, should be 192.168.2.1 along with others such as 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4, or your ISP's DNS servers.

Comment: @slm: Everything is up and running now using your final suggestion. I have tried adding the router itself as a DNS server earlier, but it did not work back then. It may had something to with the connection between the modem and router. I found out I have to power off the router for about five seconds after making changes to it, to get the connection between the two devices working. The forgotten firewall configuration made it even more cloudier, so I made the wrong conclusion this issue was Ubuntu related. I have reverted changes to `/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf` since they are no longer necessary.

Comment: @slm: Thanks a lot for all your help! Without you the router probably had undergone thorough mechanical stress testing by now. Maybe we can still transform this Q&A to something useful. But it does not belong under Unix & Linux, that is for sure.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the useful recommendations in the other answers, the avahi suite (aka Zeroconf aka Apple Bonjour) is useful in passing around and resolving local mDNS information.

Having avahi-daemon running on my home network hosts allows me to

```
ping tallguy.local
```

which required zero configuration beyond establishing a hostname `tallguy`.

Answer (score 1):

Some routers only use the `netbios` hostname.

On Debian you can

```
sudo apt-get install samba
```

and if your `/etc/hostname` is set correctly this will show up in the network without a restart.

This works for RaspberryPi, BeagleboneBlack and as far as I can remember also with Ubuntu.